# rails variable from before_configuration not available in database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, database-connection, yaml, initializer

I've written my own yaml config file as described in [railscast #85](http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-file). APP_CONFIG['FOO'] works in the initializers (e.g. sidekiq.yml), but not in database.yml (error: undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass; the '+' is being used in a concatenation: APP_CONFIG['FOO'] + 'bar').

Even putting APP_CONFIG into before_configuration did not solve this issue.

```
Rails.application.config.before_configuration do
  APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/config.yml")
end
```

Same problem. APP_CONFIG is still causing the nil:NilClass error in database.yml. So here's the question: how can i force my config.yml to be loaded before database.yml, so that it is available in database.yml as well as in the initializers (sidekiq.yml)?